# String Y Variable in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and I am trying to predict tree species from a bunch of point data describing imagery in different ways. I have created a TensorFlow model but I think I am creating my y-data incorrectly. I am using a function to change string values to numeric values between 0 and 2. The resultant prediction that I am getting back from the model is all of value 2. Could this have something to do with my y-data not being one-hot encoded? How do I get my y-data, which is string data, into this model properly?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

tree_data_file = r'\\David\Processing\p839\result_testing\first_test_feature_cols_v2.csv'

tree_data = pd.read_csv(tree_data_file)

#Make tensorflow less verbose
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

def label_fix(lable):
    if lable == 'AW':
        return 0
    elif lable == 'PB':
        return 1
    elif lable == 'SW':
        return 2

### Normalize numeric data
columns_to_normalize = ['band3_sum', 'image3b3_s', 'image_red', 'image_blue',
                        'image_gree', 'image_nir', 'image_aver', 'cohort', 'sph_total',
                        'sph_under', 'sph_over', 'crown_area', 'ci_crown_a',
                        'ndvi']
tree_data[columns_to_normalize] = tree_data[columns_to_normalize].apply( lambda x: (x - x.min())/(x.max()-x.min()))

### Create feature columns for continuous data
band3_sum = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('band3_sum')
image3b3_s = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('image3b3_s')
image_red = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('image_red')
image_blue = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('image_blue')
image_gree = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('image_gree')
image_nir = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('image_nir')
image_aver = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('image_aver')
crown_area = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('crown_area')
ci_crown_a = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('ci_crown_a')
ndvi = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('ndvi')

tree_data['sp_call'] = tree_data['sp_call'].apply(label_fix)

feat_cols = [band3_sum,image3b3_s,image_red,image_blue,image_gree,image_nir,image_aver, crown_area,ci_crown_a, ndvi]

#TRAIN TEST SPLIT
labels = tree_data['sp_call']
x_data = tree_data.drop('sp_call', axis=1)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(x_data, labels, test_size = 0.3)#, random_state=128)

input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x = X_train, y=Y_train, batch_size=100, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=True)
model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feat_cols,hidden_units=[1024,512,256,32,3],n_classes=3, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,optimizer='Adam',dropout=0.2)
model.train(input_fn=input_func, steps=20000)
results = model.evaluate(input_func)
print (results)
eval_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_test, y=Y_test, batch_size=128, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
results = model.evaluate(eval_input_func)
print (results)

pred_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_test, batch_size=100,num_epochs=1,shuffle=False)
predictions = model.predict(pred_input_func)
my_pred = list(predictions)

final_preds = []
for pred in my_pred:
    final_preds.append(pred['class_ids'])
print (final_preds)
```

UPDATE 1:
I have tried to implement the tf.one_hot as mentioned in the comments. I have changed

```
labels = tf.one_hot(tree_data['sp_call'],3)
```

This results in an error on:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(x_data, labels, test_size = 0.95)#, random_state=128)
```

stating:

```
object of type 'Tensor' has no len()
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're *not* one-hot encoding? You clearly know about it, so I'm curious if there's a reason why it's not being used?

Comment: I don't know how to do it for labels (y values). I cannot find many examples using categorical data in these models. What would the code look like to get the labels one-hot encoded and working correctly in the model?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot

Comment: The sklearn would not work because your labels is a tensor now. Try this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split